# Discord.py Мое сообщение с embed отправляется несколько раз

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Я хочу что бы бот отправлял одно сообщения за команду человеку, Но я не знаю как это сделать. А сейчас с этим кодом просто отправляется всем людям сообщения бесконечно.

```
a = 1
b = 7
@client.command()
async def testa(ctx):
    embed = discord.Embed(
        title = 'Заголовок',
        description = 'Описание',
        colour = discord.Colour.from_rgb(106, 192, 245)
    )
    
    
    
    embed = discord.Embed()
    
    embed.add_field(name='Hello by iponer', value = 'go in minecraft? :)', inline=False)
    embed.add_field(name='_ _', value = '_ _', inline=False)
    
    for line in range(a , b):
         with open("id users2.txt") as f:
            data = f.readlines()
            for line in data:
               user = await client.fetch_user(int(line.strip()))

               try:
                   await user.send(embed=embed)
               except:
                   pass

               print('Отправлено')
```

Если отправлять сообщение без эмбеда, работает все хорошо.

Comment: `отправляется несколько раз` Потому что вы его отправляете внутри цикла `for line in range(a , b):`

Comment: Так спомощью этого я перебираю все строки в документе, что бы написать всем

Comment: Так вы через `data = f.readlines()` считали весь файл в `data` и далее через `for line in data:` перебираете все строки. Разве нет?